# не запускаются все тесты в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

у меня есть 10 тестов которые отлично работают при одиночном запуске. но как толко нужно запустить все 10 кнопкой Run All в visual studio - первый тест проходит, а остальные нет. после завершения скессии первого теста видно что браузер не запускается . оставшиеся 9 тестов падают один за одним без запуска брауера с ошибкой
WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:54598

Comment: может предыдущий тест держит порт когда новый на него цепляется, попробуйте по завершению теста освобождать порт

Comment: Используйте Selenium grid для паралельного выполнения тестов либо используйте сторонние штуки: https://ultimateqa.com/parallel-test-execution-using-selenium-webdriver/ или https://stackoverflow.com/q/3840028/5752652 (сам не пользовался)